# Bool variables not being updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a object of type [ImageButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton(v=vs.110).aspx). Also I have following code:

```
 LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Log(LogLevel.Info, "###payWithVisa.Enabled ={0}; payWithVisa.Visible ={1}; canPayWithCard={2}", payWithVisa.Enabled, payWithVisa.Visible, canPayWithCard);

 payWithVisa.Enabled = canPayWithCard;
 payWithVisa.Visible = canPayWithCard;

 LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Log(LogLevel.Info, "payWithVisa.Enabled ={0}; payWithVisa.Visible ={1}; canPayWithCard={2}", payWithVisa.Enabled, payWithVisa.Visible, canPayWithCard);
```

This is the corresponding log entry:

```
2016-03-29 11:37:49.1308|INFO|###payWithVisa.Enabled =True; payWithVisa.Visible =False; canPayWithCard=True
2016-03-29 11:37:49.1348|INFO|payWithVisa.Enabled =True; payWithVisa.Visible =False; canPayWithCard=True
```

You can see that the variable `payWithVisa.Visible` does not get updated. It is still false despite assigning to it a variable with value true.

Can someone please help me clarify what is wrong?

PS. .NET framework used: 4.0

Comment: Can you check/show the variable definitions and make sure they are bool type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility (from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN):

> If a container control is not rendered, any controls that it contains will not be rendered even if you set the Visible property of an individual control to true. In that case, the individual control returns false for the Visible property even if you have explicitly set it to true. (That is, if the Visible property of the parent control is set to false, the child control inherits that setting and the setting takes precedence over any local setting.)

Therefore, you may want to check if parent control has been rendered first.